# Pyarrow append and update modes

Tags: python

With the code below, I can write the file in parquet format from disk to hdfs. But when I run the code again, it overwrites it. I want it to append or update. How can I do that? I would be glad if you help.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
from pyarrow import fs


file = "source_path"
target = "target_path"
hdfs = pa.fs.HadoopFileSystem("hdfs://okay")

df = pd.read_csv(file)
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq.write_table(table, target, filesystem=hdfs)
```